# Using lapply for k-mean clustering of many groups

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, apply, lapply

I am have about 100,000 individuals who each have trip times.  I am trying to get a clustering for each person (that is, 100,000 clustering applications in total.)  Each individual should have at least 15 trips, so I don't understand why the following error, unless that condition really isn't true. Or it could be that I am using the lapply function mistakenly?

I run the following code:

```
gr_TILPS <- lapply( split(TILPS, TILPS[,"CustomerCard_Num"]),
                    FUN=kmeansfunction)
```

I get the following error only when I include all the groups.  It worked on the first 10,000 or so.

```
Error in kmeans(x, 2) : more cluster centers than distinct data points. 
5 stop("more cluster centers than distinct data points.") 
4 kmeans(x, 2) 
3 FUN(X[[32861L]], ...) 
2 lapply(split(TILPS, TILPS[, "CustomerCard_Num"]), FUN = kmeansfunction) 
1 clusterhouseholds(TILPStest, 0.25)
```

Is there a way to check which customerid is causing this error? When I check the lengths with

```
aggregate(TILPS$col1, by=list(TILPS$CustomerCard_Num), FUN=length)
```

(Incidentally, why is this code so slow?  Isn't this embarrassingly parallel?)

they are all >15 per observation.  I am just wondering if it is possible to check WHICH customer id is causing the error, according to R.

EDIT:

I found out that the trips were not distinct in terms of the x variable, thanks. They were distinct in the sense that they occurred at different dates, but always at the same time!

Comment: Where does `kmeansfunction` come from? Usually the number of clusters is much less than the number of observations. It doesn't make sense to create a cluster for each individual. Then you're not clustering at all. Maybe i'm just not understanding what you're trying to do, but it doesn't seem to make sense.

Comment: Well, it says "more cluster centers than distinct data points". That tells me that for one of your individuals, there is only 1 trip time so finding 2 clusters is impossible.

Comment: Right, but each individual should have at least 15 trips, so this is why the error is confusing me.  I had pre-selected the individuals based on this criterion.

Comment: I found out that the trips were not distinct in terms of the x variable, thanks.  They were distinct in the sense that they occurred at different dates, but always at the same time!